# What is this plant that has been growing in my garden?

Tags: identification, plant-care

This plant looks nice but I don't know the name for this plant. It doesn't have flowers and it is about one feet wide and long. It grows on tilled soil.
Plant got a bud: [image: 2]
My First plant is so tall: [image: 3]
My second plant bud: [image: 4]
My second plant bud is so big: [image: 5]

Comment: So big, it is some perennial coming up from rootstock.

Comment: Leaves look like some kind of Amaranth, but wait for flowers to confirm it.

Comment: When would it possibly flower?

Comment: What part of the world is it growing in?

Comment: It is growing in North Carolina, United States

Comment: If it's Amaranth, it'll probably flower within a month, I'm guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my favorite plant indentification app [Plantnet](https://plantnet.org/en/), your plant is with 42% probability [Amaranthus spinosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranthus_spinosus) which is in line with what the comments suggest.

It will flower in mid-summer, depending how warm it is in your location, see e.g. [gardenersnet.com](https://www.gardenersnet.com/flower/amaranth.htm):

> Amaranth will grow tall, 1-2 feet. They will produce of blooms on strong, straight stems. Flowers are long lasting, and will bloom from mid summer until frost.

Although amaranth is annual, some may reseed themselves and produce new plants the following year.

Comment: I updated my question and my two amaranth plants (or not sure what plant it is) got buds and got really big!

Comment: The odds for *reflexed amaranth* lay at 48% now...