# What is this plant that looks like an amaranth?

Tags: identification

This plant just popped up in my garden, and I drop a lot of [amaranth](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/59335/what-is-this-plant-that-has-been-growing-in-my-garden) seeds, and it looks similar to [amaranth](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/59335/what-is-this-plant-that-has-been-growing-in-my-garden), so Is it [amaranth](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/59335/what-is-this-plant-that-has-been-growing-in-my-garden)? I have another one in a different garden too. (Ignore the other plants like lettuce, etc.) It grows in North Carolina, United States.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add your location?

Comment: Add it into the question please.

Comment: I'm guessing it's in the Mint family, whatever it is. It looks similar to a Coleus; it appears to have a square stem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went onto [plantnet.org](https://identify.plantnet.org/) and:

- First image is 74.79% Salvia hispanica L. or Chia
- Second image is 42.43% Chia
- Third image is 47.16% Chia
- Fourth image is 91.28% Chia

So I think this plant is chia or Salvia hispanica L.
Images of Chia:

[Image 1](https://bs.plantnet.org/image/o/098afb07b3c8f8aab3fbccddf3b3f962b513adc2)

[Image 2](https://bs.plantnet.org/image/m/1f8aa7dc629e89488b934ebfa1e728470e8f72f8)

Comment: The photos actually look like amaranth. Did they flower? Amaranth flowers are purple or almost white. Chia flowers have a clear blue colour.

Comment: They haven't flowered yet. Last year I thought they were weeds and pulled them up, so this time I also got a few. It makes sense how they came because I might have put chia seeds.